# how to navigate to particular .xaml page when user clicks on pivot item

Tags: uwp-xaml

What I want to do is I am having more than 10 pivot item in my app so I have added xaml page for each pivot item. For Ex. pivot Item 1,2,3,4.. I have added .xaml pages as P_item1.xaml,P_item 2 .xaml and so on I want user to navigate on this .xaml page when user clicks on pivot item. Also I dont want to add any xaml control in this pivot item content instead I want to add it to respective xaml page for their pivot item which I have added for each pivot item

pivot_page.xaml

```
                <PivotItem Header="Item1">
                  <pivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="item 2">
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="item2">
                </PivotItem>
                <PivotItem Header="item 2"> 
                </PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe the event `SelectionChanged` applied to the Pivot control.

But I think that something is wrong with the user experience, because if you want to navigate to the `PivotItem` "Item 3", for example, you must pass through "Item 1" and "Item 2". And if you detect the `SelectionChanged` and navigate to a new page...simply you can't get to the "Item 3". But maybe I'am missing something.